# git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey), but only from crontab

Tags: bash, git, ssh, cron, bitbucket

I have a linux shell script `cron.sh` that mainly just pushes code to bitbucket:

```
#!/bin/bash

# 1. do some stuff

# 2. push to bitbucket
cd /home/abmc/repo
git add .
git commit -m "Cron data update"
git push
```

I can run the script just fine from the shell. No errors.
However, I get the following error when script runs from crontab (as the same user):

```
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have double checked the ssh key configuration and the ~/.ssh permissions and all seems fine.
It is very puzzling that it fails only when run from crontab.
I cannot figure it out.

Comment: You're absolutely sure that the crontab executes as the same user?

Comment: Try running `git config --list` in both environments and see if the output is different.

Comment: How did you edit the crontab? To make sure the script will be executed by the same user we should use  `crontab -e` command to add the task to cron.

As @JohnGordon suggested. Could please run the `crontab -l` command as the same user used to run `cron.sh` without errors? The command will show your crontab entries so you can make sure the `cron.sh` really executes with the context and permissions of the same user.

Comment: Does your ssh key have a passphrase? Please be reminded cron jobs don't have access to `ssh-agent` so only passphraseless keys work.

Comment: **@phd** : Unsure. How do I check?  How do I make it passphraseless if so?  
**@JohnGordon** : Yes. I am absolutely sure it executes as same user and `git config --list` in both environments returns exactly the same. Just checked.  
**@MarcinKłopotek** : Always edited with `crontab -e`. No errors with `contrab -l`

Answer (score 1):

@phd add it right. Key had a passphrase. Regenerating the key without a passphrase and adding new key to bitbucket solved the issue.